# How to make on hover take 100% of page width up

Tags: html, css

I have this navi bar... When I hover over an option I want it to take up 100% width so it spans across the entire screen. When I change the width amounts to 100% it just gets smaller, Not bigger.

HTML

```
<div id="cssmenu">

            <ul>
                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Details</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <?php include 'summary.php';?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>.....</span></a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen+Mono);
        /* Starter CSS for Menu */
        #cssmenu {
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          border: 0;
          width: auto;
        }
        #cssmenu ul,
        #cssmenu li {
          list-style: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        #cssmenu ul {
          position: relative;
          z-index: 597;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li {
          float: left;
          min-height: 1px;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li.hover,
        #cssmenu ul li:hover {
          position: relative;
          z-index: 599;
          cursor: default;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul {
          visibility: hidden;
          position: absolute;
          top: 100%;
          left: 0;
          z-index: 598;
          width: 100%;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li {
          float: none;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul ul {
          top: 0;
          left: 190px;
          width: 700px;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
          visibility: visible;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul {
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul {
          margin-top: 0;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li {
          font-weight: normal;
        }
        #cssmenu a {
          display: block;
          line-height: 1em;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        /* Custom CSS Styles */
        #cssmenu {
          background: #333333;
          border-bottom: 4px solid #1b9bff;
          font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
          font-size: 12px;
        }
        #cssmenu > ul {
          *display: inline-block;
        }
        #cssmenu:after,
        #cssmenu ul:after {
          content: '';
          display: block;
          clear: both;
        }
        #cssmenu ul {
          text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul {
          border-top: 4px solid #1b9bff;
          text-transform: none;
          min-width: 1200px;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul a {
          background: #1b9bff;
          color: #ffffff;
          border: 1px solid #0082e7;
          border-top: 0 none;
          line-height: 150%;
          padding: 16px 20px;
          font-size: 12px;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul ul {
          border-top: 0 none;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li {
          position: relative;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
          border-top: 1px solid #0082e7;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
          background: #4eb1ff;
          color: #ffffff;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
          -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
          border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
          -moz-background-clip: padding;
          -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1b9bff;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1b9bff;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1b9bff;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child:hover > a {
          -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
          border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
          -moz-background-clip: padding;
          -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
          content: '+';
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          right: 15px;
          margin-top: -8px;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li:hover > a,
        #cssmenu ul li.active > a {
          background: #1b9bff;
          color: #ffffff;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
          content: '+';
          margin-left: 5px;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li.last ul {
          left: auto;
          right: 0;
        }
        #cssmenu ul li.last ul ul {
          left: auto;
          right: 99.5%;
        }
        #cssmenu a {
          background: #333333;
          color: #CBCBCB;
          padding: 0 20px;
        }
        #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
          line-height: 48px;
          font-size: 12px;
        }
```

It needs to be 100% not like 1200px because I want it to fit correctly on different screens.

Comment: What is supposed to be 100% of what? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: if you look at the html part, When you Hover over details... it creates a submenu below it in blue... that submenu is 1200px wide.. I want it to just be 100% of the screen.. But when I change it to 100% it gets really small. I just want the sub menu to take up the complete width

Comment: Could you reduce your example code to *just enough* to demo the problem...there's an awful lot of unnecessary code in there.

Comment: Nothing there is unnecessary... There is only a tiny bit of HTML.. the very BASIC of what needs to be seen. And you NEED to see all the CSS that has to do with the menu

Comment: With CSS3 you have VW and VH (viewport width & viewport height) change 100% to 100vw, here the element take 100% of the parent

Comment: @AnTSaSk That worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @AnTSaSk put that in a answer pls so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to take a percent of the viewport, with CSS3 you can use VW (viewport width) and VH (viewport height)

Answer (score 0):

to make the submenu have width as 100%, the #cssmenu should have position relative added to it. remove the position relative applied to the li.hover